# Opacity cuts off text

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a `<span>` tag with some text in it.  This tag is being used as a "meter" basically.  I change the width of it based on some progress.

It looks a little something like this:

```html
<div>
    <span id="test">Words</span>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```css
#test {
    width: 1%;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;

    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

The text overflows outside of the `<span>` and that's exactly what I want.

In IE8, the text does *not* overflow!  The problem is the `filter: alpha(opacity=50);`.  If I remove it, the text is overflowed properly.

Why does opacity affect the overflow in IE8?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mxd27/show/ (edit it at: http://jsfiddle.net/mxd27/)

Comment: Try overflow:visible it.

Comment: @MilchePatern: Tried, didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add some markup and styles:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress"></div>
    <span id="test">Words</span>
</div>

.container{
    position: relative;
    display: block;   
    zoom: 1;
}

.progress{
    width: 10%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    zoom: 1;
}

#test {
    position: relative;  
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    display:block;

}
```

Comment: Why is `container` set to `inline-block`?  That makes the width of the progress bar the same as the width of the text, and that's not what I want.

Comment: Also, I kinda wanted the words to have 50% opacity, too.  Oddly, adding `filter: alpha(opacity=50);` to `#test` didn't work.

Comment: sorry, for you better to set display:block for .container

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does work! IE 8 doesn't like opacity on elements that aren't `block` or `inline-block`. My solution is: http://jsfiddle.net/MLLB3/3/